# Combination rate of atomic hydrogen

Tags: physical-chemistry, hydrogen

So, let's say you have a vessel of atomic hydrogen (no need to inquire into the source, right?). Assume no ionizing radiation. Eventually, you'll wind up with a vessel of molecular hydrogen. How long will this take?

It seems pretty obvious that this will depend on pressure and temperature, but my Google efforts aren't getting me anywhere.

As context, I'm interested in getting a rough measure of the fraction of atomic hydrogen within the 55 ppm abundance of hydrogen in the atmosphere. I expect it's very small, of course, but "very small" isn't much of a specific answer.

Comment: In equilibrium, shouldn't you be able to use the relative energies of atomic and molecular hydrogen to get the fraction? Why do you need this rate?

Comment: @mmesser314 - I'm about to get into an argument with a crank, and would like some ammunition. I suppose your approach would work, but it's outside my area of competence, let alone expertise.

Comment: You have my sympathy. Arguing with a crank generally does not convince him, even if the logic is obviously correct. That is part of the definition of crank. I recommend a different hobby.

Comment: @mmesser314 - Oh, I don't expect to convince him. I just want to make my arguments solid.